# Is it possible to check if a method or function exists in the component controller?

Tags: custom-component, model, controller

I have a custom component that will be using various AJAX calls, based on outside settings.

How can I load "this" controller from the View or Model to determine if a method/function exists, i.e. PHP `method_exists` and/or `is_callable`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out how to use `$this`, but it was pretty straightforward otherwise.  This checks to see if the `add` method exists in the Article controller.

```
$ToolsClass = 'ContentControllerArticle';
$methodToFind = 'add';
JLoader::register($ToolsClass, JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/controllers/article.php');
if (!method_exists($ToolsClass, $methodToFind)){
    echo "Content Controller Function '{$methodToFind}' not found";
}
```